# Simulate transactions for Authorize.Net ARB subscription

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I'm building a simple reporting system that lists out the transactions of an authorize.net subscription (ARB).

Is there a way to generate or simulate transactions for a subscription without waiting for the interval periods? The shortest interval period is 7 days. I can't wait 7 days for one transaction to process.

Comment: There isn't but do you really need to? What are you hoping to accomplish? You probably can use webhooks or silent post to do what you need as the actual processing of the payment is not important for local dev and testing.

Comment: @JohnConde I mean why would test data be important to development?

Comment: You don't need Authorize.Net to actually process a subscription to do your dev or testing. You can simulate a subscription payment on demand which will accomplish exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JohnConde That was my original question (see post title!). How does one simulate a subscription payment on demand?

Comment: I go back to my original question, what are you hoping to accomplish? What are you testing? ARB? Webhooks? Silent Post?

Comment: @JohnConde I'm creating ARB's for several merchants and am simply creating a UI that lists out all the transactions for each ARB and merchant. I am using several Authorize.Net API calls to achieve this:

1. getCustomerProfileByMerchantId(), 2. getTransactionListForCustomer() and am trying to determine if the code is feasible. I'm not sure if getTransactionListForCustomer() returns transactions for a subscription, for example.

Comment: Well it looks like getTransactionListForCustomer() doesn't even return transactions under subscriptions so I'll need to use getSubscriptions() with the include transactions flag set. Unfortunately this only returns the last 20 transactions, nor does it include the charged amount, which means I have to make yet another API call after this one!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately getting transactions organized by subscription is not possible. It would be a great addition to their API.